# Bypass a DLL call in C# with fixed value?

Tags: c#, arrays, dllimport

I have a DllImport that calls for an integer with two byte references. I don't have the source code to the DLL and the DLL is responding with an incorrect value.

```
[DllImport("asd.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int state(ref byte ktime, ref byte is_h);
```

AFAIK from my limited programming knowledge, this call will pass an array with 15 bytes of data as suggested by the code that wants said data?

```
byte[] array2 = new byte[14];
byte[] array3 = new byte[1];
int num = state(ref array2[0], ref array3[0]);
```

This said data is a timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) and a single digit from 0 to 7 in a 15 byte array.
So I should see something like 202112060141307 for example.

What I need to do, is instead of the software reaching out to this DLL, for it to just pass a 15 byte array of my choosing.
The reason I am not going through the code and editing it is that this is called like 100 times and we have multiple versions of the code that we are testing so 100x how many versions we have.

Presuming I am heading in the correct direction but I am completely lost. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question or what the problem is

Comment: So you have an export from a dll, that has takes 2 arrays of bytes, and you want to pass it one array?

Comment: Is there any practical reason why you have 100 versions of the code you are testing? If there is not then you should learn about source control.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a little mediator...which keeps the same signature...so that your 100s of places that use the "state" call don't need to be edited....you can then choose whether to call the real underlying DLL function, or to just set your "test" data.

This only works if you have one place (or only a few places) in your code where you do the `DLLImport` of the function, and can change it.

This would mean just changing the signature of your `DLLImport`.

```
[DllImport("asd.dll", EntryPoint = "state", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int asd_state(ref byte ktime, ref byte is_h);

public static int state(ref byte ktime, ref byte is_h)
{
    // some flag to control which is called or you could
    // use an #if definition

    if (callunderlyingdll)
        return asd_state(ref ktime, ref is_h);
    else
    {
        ktime = ..your array here..
        is_h = ..your value here...

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Another way, is to use a hook to hook the "C#" "state" function to point it to your bit of code to set the state values for return....you'd need a hook library to do that e.g.

https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony